# Bluemix project owner change

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops

If an employee who is the owner of a Bluemix DevOps project leaves the company, who can and how do we change the owner of that project to his replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to have several administrators and to transfer ownership of projects. There is some basic [overview of account management for DevOps](https://hub.jazz.net/docs/projectadmin/).

If your scenario is that the employee was the only administrator (like the sole superuser leaving the company) you would need contact Bluemix account management for a solution.